# T-Bird header / mail inbox now with excessive details after changing from XYZ@optonline.net to @gmail.com

Tags: thunderbird

After changing my email to @gmail.com I see on the header:

1. FROM: (sender email addr)
2. TO: Me (recipient addr)
3. Subject:
4. Date:
5. Msg ID: (long trail of characters an email addr.)
6. User Agent: Mozilla, Win NT, Win10, win 64, Gecko, numbers, T-bird...
7. Delivered to:

How do I get rid of the excessive lines #2 Me (but email addr. only), 5, 6 and 7 ?

Comment: Most of these are standard headers, and the majority are mandatory per RFCs. (User-Agent is superfluous, but probably a vestige of the shared code base with Firefox.) You can configure your email client to not display them - most will not show most of them most of the time by default (but you can see them when you view the message source, or configure your client to display more headers). It's not clear if you are asking how to make Thunderbird not put those headers in the raw message (basically, you can't, and mustn't) or if you have a problem with configuring which headers it displays to you

Comment: What’s this question about? Received mails? Their source code? Or some GUI elements in Thunderbird? If it’s in the GUI, please provide a screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

The `User-Agent:` header can be disabled through "Config Editor" in a similar way to Firefox:

- https://www.ghacks.net/2012/09/08/hide-the-user-agent-when-sending-emails-with-thunderbird/
- https://support.mozilla.org/gl/questions/1375574
- https://support.mozilla.org/ha/questions/1323705

All other headers are either mandatory, and/or outside your control.

The `To:` header doesn't actually contain "Me" – that's only what Thunderbird *shows* for messages received to your own address. In reality, it contains the name and address that the *sender* specifies (often taken from the sender's address book). If someone sends a message to `H. Jh <hjh@example.com>` that's what their mail app will put in the `To:` header.

The `Message-ID:` header doesn't contain any email addresses. It's more or less required for all email messages to have an unique ID – if the sender's mail app doesn't add one, then the sender's mail *server* will. (That's not unique to Gmail.)

The `Delivered-To:` header isn't added by the sender – it's added by the *recipient's* mail server and shows which mailbox the message was delivered *to* (often used for filtering when they have several addresses going to the same location).